# Concatenate data (matrices) in separate sheets (Gnumeric)

Tags: spreadsheet, gnumeric

I need to "concatenate" data from two sheets into a third sheet. I need to do this in Gnumeric, but presumably it should be doable with other spreadsheet programs as well.

Sheet 1:

```
| A         | B  |
|-----------|----|
| John      | 10 |
| Jane      | 20 |
| Mike      | 30 |
```

Sheet 2:

```
| A         | B  |
|-----------|----|
| Sally     | 40 |
| Pete      | 45 |
```

I intend for these data to get "combined" on Sheet 3 automatically irrespective of how many rows are present in Sheet 1 and 2:
Unfortunately no combination of Concatenate and Sheet referencing seems to give me a way around not having to know the number of rows in each sub-set of data.

```
| A         | B  |
|-----------|----|
| John      | 10 |
| Jane      | 20 |
| Mike      | 30 |
| Sally     | 40 |
| Pete      | 45 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Gnumeric and a quick look at the list of [Gnumeric
functions](http://www.gnumeric.org/functions.shtml) didn't give me enough info.  I can however provide options for Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel which you can use or adapt to Gnumeric.

### Google Sheets

```
={ FILTER(Sheet1!A:B,(Sheet1!A:A<>"")+(Sheet1!B:B<>""));
   FILTER(Sheet2!A:B,(Sheet2!A:A<>"")+(Sheet2!B:B<>"")) }
```

- In FILTER `+` is equivalent to `OR`
- FILTER range `A:B` where there is anything in column `A` or in  column `B`
- Brackets `{}` in sheets indicate an array, and the semi-colon `;` is a row separator
- A single empty array will return a `#VALUE!` error *****

### Microsoft Excel

```
=VSTACK( FILTER(Sheet1!A:B,(Sheet1!A:A<>"")+(Sheet1!B:B<>"")),
         FILTER(Sheet2!A:B,(Sheet2!A:A<>"")+(Sheet2!B:B<>"")) )
```

- VSTACK allows vertically stacking arrays in Excel.
- Arrays in the list to stack are separated by a `,`
- A single empty array will return a `#CALC!` error *****

***** To handle errors, the formula can be wrapped in IFERROR or if preferred, each individual FILTER function can be wrapped in IFERROR so one error doesn't affect the entire formula.

```
# Gooogle Sheets
--------------------------
={ IFERROR(
     FILTER(Sheet1!A:B,(Sheet1!A:A<>"")+(Sheet1!B:B<>"")),
     {"",""} );
   IFERROR(
     FILTER(Sheet2!A:B,(Sheet2!A:A<>"")+(Sheet2!B:B<>"")),
     {"",""} ) }

# Microsoft Excel
--------------------------
=VSTACK(
   IFERROR(
     FILTER(Sheet1!A:B,(Sheet1!A:A<>"")+(Sheet1!B:B<>"")),
     HSTACK("", "") ),
   IFERROR(
     FILTER(Sheet2!A:B,(Sheet2!A:A<>"")+(Sheet2!B:B<>"")),
     HSTACK("", "") ) )
```